# HTML-iFrame PDF toolbar missing

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

iframe pdf toolbar is missing in IE , works fine chrome and Firefox

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_tutorial.pdf" width="800px" height="900px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```